# Allowed Options in NSJSONSerialization class method dataWithJSONObject:options:error

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsjsonserialization

can anyone please tell me where to find all options that we can provide in the following method:

`dataWithJSONObject:options:error`

I have been trying to search for over an hour.. but was not able to find any except `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`

what is `kNilOptions` used for??

Comment: Where's that Picard meme. WTF no zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` is the only option supported at this time. You can provide 0, of course, if you don't want pretty printing. You can find a discussion of it at the bottom of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

`kNilOptions` equates to 0, but it's included as part of the Carbon APIs, not Cocoa.

Comment: I came across several code snippets that use kNilOptions passed into options.. we can still use it right?? are there any other similar options that we can use??

Comment: As long as it's available to you, I guess there's no problem. I personally wouldn't use it, but 0 instead; I wouldn't want to introduce any dependence on Carbon unless I needed it for other things.

Comment: Swift:  do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(myArrsOrDicts, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }